# Read permissions is not enough for Join a community SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, community

I have a sub-site Community. On home page of subsite , I have a button **Join a community**. Refer to this article [Community](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-a-community-bc9f0396-8893-4474-8b18-822d8def7b96?ui=fr-FR&rs=en-US&ad=BE), user can click this button, and then the button hides.

If user has Read permission, when he clicks button, there will a request send to site administrator. And administrator should give him Contribute permission.

In my site, user cannot have permission to **delete list item**, which is included in Contribute permission. So I create a new permission level which contains view, add, update list items and documents. But it does not work unless user has right to delete item.

Which permission for Join a community in sharepoint 2013? Delete item is a necessary permission ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work it needs to be a Root Site Collection. It does not work on Subsites.

Comment: Which permission is necessary in a subsite ?

Comment: @MKQian user need to have Read (Visitor) in order to join a Community site.

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: Microsoft Technet and i have  also been trying this myself earlier.

Comment: @MagnusG if user has Read permission, when he clicks button, there will a request send to site administrator. And administrator should give him Contribute permission.  In my site, user cannot have permission to delete list item, which is included in Contribute. So I create a new permission level which contains view, add, update list items and documents. But it does not work unless user has right to delete item. I think maybe there are others permissions I can give to user.